# trouble with renaming column names using if else in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have 60 columns, which i would like to rename these columns and add to dataframe. each column should be renamed, so i have used elif statements i.e 40 statements. But, when i do that only some columns are printing other coulmns are not even present in my file. i dont know, where i went wrong.

for example: If i have renamed 10 columns only 5 columns are printing.

i have tried in the following way

```
//if column names with signature1, then following chages should be done...

if "vat-signature1" in f:


                        df=df.rename({'in_by_19_vat-signature1':'in_by_19_vat-sign-01', 'in_by_24_vat-signature1':'in_by_24_vat-signature1',  'ou_by_19_vat-signature1':'ou_by_19_vat-signaturn-01'}, axis=1)
                        dataframe_collection["vat-sign-01"]=df

 elif "vat-signature2" in f:


                        df=df.rename({'in_by_19_vat-signature2':'in_by_19_vat-sign-02', 'in_by_24_vat-signature2':'in_by_24_vat-sign-02',  'ou_by_19_vat-signature2':'ou_by_19_vat-sign-02'}, axis=1)
                        dataframe_collection["vat-sign-02"]=df
.....
.....
.....
.....
same for 60 columns...
 else
     dataframe_collection[f.split('_')[1]]=df 
//otherwise print the same filenames i.e take from f.spilt
return dataframe_collection
```

But when i do in this way only 20 columns are renamed and other columns are not even present in my csv file. where i am writing this dataframe to a csv file.